# Unity 5, destroy(game.Object)

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I just started  to make 2D game for myself, I've got a problem.
I have a gameObject moving through the sreen from right to the left, I need to destroy it when it leaves the screen.
I've created "object_killer", added BoxCollider2D component, IsTrigger.
This is my small script (C#):

```
 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
           if (other.tag == "rektcar")
            {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            }
    }
```

But nothing happens - my gameObject is moving far away from the screen.
"object_killer" has rektcar tag.

Comment: Why not debug your own code and see what's going on? Put `Debug.Log("Triggered");` inside `OnTriggerEnter` function then also put `Debug.Log("Triggered rektcar");` in the if statement. Tell us the result.

Comment: Sorry, didn't say about it. I tried it, but there's no result. Seems like function wasn't even called but I dont understand why :\

Answer (score 1):

Do both of the colliding objects have a 2D collider? 
Also, if you're making a 2D game with 2D colliders use

```
OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) {  }
```

Read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used `OnTriggerEnter` you should make sure your object has selected `IsTrigger` property. If you don't want to use trigger you can change `OnTriggerEnter` to `OnCollisionEnter`.

Comment: Yeah, i've checked IsTrigger, nothing happens. Tried to apply "IsTrigger" to both objects, to any one of em - still nothing.